# Show that $\frac{\int_\Omega e^{v^2}v^2}{\int_\Omega v^2} \geq \frac{\int_\Omega e^{u^2}u^2}{\int_\Omega u^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I would like to ask if the following statement is true or not:

Let $u,v:\Omega\subset%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{N}\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
~(\Omega$ is bounded)$;~v\geq u>0.$ Is it true that $$
\frac{%
%TCIMACRO{\dint \limits_{\Omega}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Omega}}
%EndExpansion
e^{v^{2}}v^{2}}{%
%TCIMACRO{\dint \limits_{\Omega}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Omega}}
%EndExpansion
v^{2}}\geq\frac{%
%TCIMACRO{\dint \limits_{\Omega}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Omega}}
%EndExpansion
e^{u^{2}}u^{2}}{%
%TCIMACRO{\dint \limits_{\Omega}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Omega}}
%EndExpansion
u^{2}}?
$$

Comment: This is not true. I've checked via numerrical expriment

Comment: @Norbert Can you provide any details of your experiment?

Comment: Take $N=1$, $\Omega=[0,1]$, $u=a_1\chi_{[0,1/2]}+a_2\chi_{[1/2,1]}$ and $v=b_1\chi_{[0,1/2]}+b_2\chi_{[1/2,1]}$. Varying parameters $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ in the range $[0,1]$ you can find a conterexample to your conjecture. I think one can provide a counterexample even with smooth functions.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying a similar thing by hand but didn't come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Norbert let $N=1$, $\Omega=[0,1]$ and consider the family of functions:
$$
u(x;a_1,a_2) = a_1\chi_{[0,1/2]}(x) + a_2\chi_{[1/2,1]}(x).
$$
Compute
$$
\int_\Omega u^2 \; dx = \frac12 a_1^2 + \frac12 a_2^2
$$
and
$$
\int_\Omega e^{u^2}u^2 \; dx = \frac12e^{a_1^2}a_1^2 + \frac12e^{a_2^2}a_2^2,
$$
noting that
$$
f(a_1,a_2) = \frac{\int_\Omega e^{u^2}u^2}{\int_\Omega u^2} = \frac{e^{a_1^2}a_1^2 + e^{a_2^2}a_2^2}{a_1^2+a_2^2}.
$$
Simplifying the situation further, set $a_1=1$ and observe that
$$
f(1,t) = \frac{e + e^{t^2}t^2}{1+t^2}
$$
is a [decreasing function on the interval $t\in(0.1,0.6)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%2bx%5E2%20e%5E%28x%5E2%29%29/%281%2bx%5E2%29%20from%20x=0%20to%20x=1). Therefore,
$$
f(1,0.4) < f(1,0.2)
$$
implying that
\begin{align}
u &= \chi_{[0,1/2]} + 0.2\chi_{[1/2,1]} \\
v &= \chi_{[0,1/2]} + 0.4\chi_{[1/2,1]}
\end{align}
are counterexamples.